# What is taught in lessons using the CVT method?

Tags: technique, voice, teaching

I'm interested in doing some vocal lessons with a [Complete Vocal Technique (CVT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_Vocal_Institute#Complete_Vocal_Technique) coach. I've read around the concept and seen a few exercises, even had a taster session but what if one was taking regular lessons what would typically be covered and how would this vary from week to week?

It seems CVT is quite a well structured teaching system so while every teacher-pupil interaction is of course going to be somewhat different, the content is presumably defined enough that this question *is* answerable on some level?

Comment: I suppose we might have instructors in this system on here, but have you tried asking one directly? Surely they'd be the best able to say.

Answer (score 1):

CVT is sort of a commercial product, and you can learn about it on the internet. There is even a phone app explaining various parts of the method.

On the other hand the teachers have their own background and experience, and possibly only at some point of their career got involved in learning and getting certified in given method. The details of *how* they teach may vary. I'd recommend contacting the teacher, or perhaps looking for opinions of their students, or even trying to get some lessons and see if you like working with the particular teacher.

Comment: I've done some looking online but cannot find what the 'material' or 'syllabus' is, you might say. Only the more high-level theory behind it. If we compared a school math curriculum, every teacher will do things differently but the core stuff you actually get taught will be pretty similar - that's kind of what I'm aiming at, if my question wasn't clear.

Comment: @Mr.Boy as far as I know no strict syllabus exists, and a teacher will adjust the pace and the order for each student individually (in CVT and other methods).